# Matching address in mbox format in python

Tags: python, regex, email

I am trying to get the address of the sender in mbox formated mails in python. When I get the line that contains the sender, it looks like `From: Mister X <misterx@domain>`. I am able to retrieve the mail address with, for example, `re.findall('<[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+>', str)`. I think that should be fine since email addresses, as far as I know, cannot contain any other characters. What I do not understand is why the expression `<*@*>`, which I expected to match any characters in the email address does not work at all. In fact, `re.findall('<*@*>', 'From: Mister X <misterx@domain>')`returns `['>']`.

Comment: Keep in mind that regex matching is different from glob matching. In glob matching `*` is the wildcard to match any number of characters. In regex, if you want to achieve the same result, you use `.*` (The dot is the wildcard for 1 character, and the asterisk indicates this wildcard repeated at least 0 times).

Comment: You forgot `_` in the bracket. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<*` means: "the character **<** zero or more times". You are looking for `<.*@.*>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

`why the expression <*@*>, which I expected to match any characters in the email address does not work at all.`

Because you are using `re` module that evaluate your expression `<*@*>` as **regular expression**.  If you want to make your expression evaluated as **wildcard**, use `fnmatch` module. But `fnmatch` have only function that checks if string matches or not. So you can't get matches by using `fnmatch`. From your question, It seems you want to retrieve mail address, so you shouldn't use `fnmatch` module. Just use `re` module to get matches.

I think you are just confusing regular expression between wildcard.